# Twisted: static URL dispatch 'No Such Resource' error

Tags: python, twisted, twisted.web

I'm learning to use twisted.web from [web-in-60-seconds](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/web-in-60/index.html) . In the section Static URL Dispatch [(link here)](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/web-in-60/static-dispatch.html), I ran the code as it is, and when I connect to localhost at port 8880 it displays 'No Such Response' error. Here's the code.

```
from twisted.web.server import Site
from twisted.web.resource import Resource
from twisted.internet import reactor, endpoints
from twisted.web.static import File

root = Resource()
root.putChild("foo", File("/tmp"))
root.putChild("bar", File("/lost+found"))
root.putChild("baz", File("/opt"))

factory = Site(root)
endpoint = endpoints.TCP4ServerEndpoint(reactor, 8880)
endpoint.listen(factory)
reactor.run()
```

urls tried

```
http://localhost:8880/foo
http://localhost:8880/bar
http://localhost:8880/baz
```

I tried changing paths inside `File` object and tried some random ports and it still isn't working. What's wrong with this ?

Comment: Is nobody gonna answer ?!!

Comment: Which OS? And have you got all the right permissions? I've tried your code and works fine AFAIK. Which browser do you use? Which Python version? Can you show a 'curl -v' invocation with the result of your problem?

Comment: I'm on macOS Sierra, python 3.5.2. Browsers were safari, chrome, firefox. curl shows 404 response code

Comment: it was python version problem. I just ran in python 2.7.10 and it worked well.  thanks.

Comment: @Airbear - I think that is a problem with `twisted` then. I just ran into the same issue but my requirements are such that I cannot use Python2.x. Using Python2 shouldn't be the answer imho.